# Android application showing default icon launcher

Tags: android, gradle, drawable, launcher

I'm having a problem with my android application icon launcher.
I have drawables for hdpi, xhdpi, mdpi and xxhdpi.

There is the code of my `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApp"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_app">
...
</application>
```

In some devices the icon launcher appears normally. However, in other devices, the application shows the default package icon launcher.

Besides that, I am using Gradle in my project. Does Gradle have any relation with kind of problem?

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: have you provided ic_launcher_app for all the drawable folders you have in your project?

Comment: As @RajenRaiyarela says, if you haven't the icon for each resolution in some device could shows the default icon. Check all folders (xxxhdpi, xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi etc etc..)

Comment: you have put logo in all folders like ldpi,mdpi,xxdpi, It work like if any device have ldpi type screen than this device will use ldpi folder's  icons. and so. got it?

Comment: Make sure that app icon (ic_launcher_app) is in all folders and delete default app icon (ic_launcher). Then see what happens when there is no ic_launcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your icon in all resolution folders like below:

```
 res/...
        drawable-ldpi/...
            ic_launcher_app.png
        drawable-mdpi/...
            ic_launcher_app.png
        drawable-hdpi/...
            ic_launcher_app.png
        drawable-xhdpi/...
            ic_launcher_app.png
        drawable-xxhdpi/...
            ic_launcher_app.png
```

Comment: Thanks for all answers! It blends!